# How to use dynamic table of every month in the insert statement while one static value we are passing in one column

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

In one Stored proc, I used `insert into` statement i declare one variable as v_tbl_name which is dynamic. I am going to use this dynamic table in `insert into` block while we are passing one static value in one column but getting error. Here is the sample code-

```
declare
v_tbl_name varchar2(5) := NULL;
v_gen_tbl constant varchar2(50) := 'arch_tbl_mon';   --table name
v_sql varchar2(10000);

begin
 v_tbl_name := v_gen_tbl || '_' ||  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MON');
v_sql := 'insert into tbl                 --- another table going to insert
 (select ''abc'' as col1, ........
  from '||v_tbl_name||');'
execute immediate v_sql;
commit;
end;
```

Here `'abc'` static value as column. After executing the above code, It is generating an err like `Encountered the symbol "Execute"`.

Comment: Answer: don't. Put all of your data in one table with an additional column for the month

Comment: Agree with @Nick.McDermaid.  What you are attempting to do violates every principle of data design.  Even if what you are attempting was essentially a valid design (it isn't) how would you distinguish table name for APRIL of one year vs APRIL of another?

Comment: @EdStevens Here 'abc' static value as column so that's why not able to execute the stored proc. Could you please do in another way because i have already tried it. It is generating an err like `Encountered the symbol ' `.

Comment: The "another way" is to use proper data design - one table, and add a 'month' column to it so as to differentiate what you are trying to do with an ever increasing number of tables.  Your current design is like driving past a 'bridge out ahead' sign, @Nick.McDermaid and I are pointing out that sign, and you just ask how to make your car go faster toward that 'bridge out'. Oh, and that 'month' column in your properly designed table should probably be of DATE datatype.

Comment: @EdStevens OK as per requirement all the backup of the data of every month will be stored into the particular table of every month that's why i separate for every month table. But getting err because `'abc'` as an Encountered symbol.

Comment: Well, I've told you what I would do, but you choose to ignore it.  See http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
declare
v_tbl_name varchar2(5) := NULL;
v_gen_tbl constant varchar2(50) := 'arch_tbl_mon';   --table name
v_sql varchar2(1000);
begin
 v_tbl_name := v_gen_tbl || '_' ||  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MON');
 v_sql:= 'insert into tbl                 --- another table going to insert
  select 'abc' as col1, ........
  from  '||v_tbl_name;
  execute immediate v_sql;
  commit;
end;
```

Demo:

```
declare
v_tbl_name varchar2(5) := NULL;
v_gen_tbl constant varchar2(50) := 'arch_tbl_mon';   --table 
v_sql varchar2(1000);
begin

 v_tbl_name := 'DEPT';
 v_sql :='insert into tbl   select *  from '||v_tbl_name;
 execute immediate v_sql;  
end;

Exec:

SQL> select * from tbl;
     DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
     ---------- -------------------- --------------------
        1      XXX                 YYY
```

Edit:

> Here 'abc' static value as column so that's why not able to execute
>   the stored proc. It is generating an err like Encountered the symbol '
>   abc '.

See below demo:

Table `tbl` is being populated with static value `abc` from select statement:

```
SQL> select * from tbl;
    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC                  B
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ---
```

After Execution:

```
 declare
    v_tbl_name varchar2(5) := NULL;
    v_gen_tbl constant varchar2(50) := 'arch_tbl_mon';   --table 
    v_sql varchar2(1000);
    begin

     v_tbl_name := 'DEPT';
     v_sql :='insert into tbl (deptno,dname,loc,b) select a.*, ''abc''  from '||v_tbl_name||' a'; 
     execute immediate v_sql;  
     Commit;
    end;
```

OUTPUT

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM TBL;
    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC                  B
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ---
       100 Executive            USA                  abc
```

Final Edit:

You didnot follow what I showed to you hence you landed into the problem. Follow my inline comments. Please replace the column name where mentioned and it would be resolved.

```
declare
v_tbl_name varchar2(5) := NULL;
v_gen_tbl constant varchar2(50) := 'arch_tbl_mon';   --table name
v_sql varchar2(10000);

begin
 v_tbl_name := v_gen_tbl || '_' ||  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MON');
 v_sql := 'insert into tbl(col1,.....<all columns>)                 --- another table going to insert
  select ''abc'' as col1, a.col2........<other columns a.<columns>
  from '||v_tbl_name||' a';
execute immediate v_sql;
commit;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but here 'abc' static value as column so that's why not able to execute the stored proc. Could you please do in another way because i have already tried it. It is generating an err like `Encountered the symbol ' `.

Comment: This is the right answer except they got the source and target table around the wrong way.

Comment: @user8487380 Edit your question and post what you have tried so far.

Comment: @user8487380 Read my updated answer. You didnot follow what i suggested and that why you landed up to the problem.